# CSS: Dropdown Menus: Getting Submenus To LIne Up With Menus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to develop a drop down menu for a web site.  I'm using this nice library I found for menus called "ddmenu".   I customized it to get it close to where I want to be.   My problem is that I can't get the **right** edge of the submenus to line up with the **right** edges of the parent menus.   All 3 menus are skewed to the right or left.....and by different amounts.

I just don't have enough CSS to easily understand the library.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Thanks much in advance

Steve

**My menu.html file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>NSD: NOAA Staff Directory</title>
       <style type="text/css">
        .nav_user_menu
        {
            float: right;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight:bold; 
        }
        .nav_logout_link
        {
            display: block;
            float: right;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight:bold; 
            border-left: 1px solid;
        }

    </style>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="search_files/ddmenu.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="JavaScript" "text="" javascript"="" src="search_files/ddmenu.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>




    <ul id="ddmenu">

        <li>
            <a href="#">A Generic Link</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Choice 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Choice 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Choice 3</a> </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Help</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu Choice 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu Choice 2 </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Submenu Choice 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
        </li> 


        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Mailing Addresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Regions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Employee Types</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Employee Flags</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Production Control Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add/Edit ACME Report Access</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>

       <!-- Log Out Button ---------------------------------------------------->
       <div class="nav_logout_link">

           <a href="#">Log Out</a>
       </div>


        <div class = "nav_user_menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Update My Record</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Update My ACME Sales Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Update My Voluntary ACME Sales Statistics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Reports</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li> 
        </div>


    </ul><!-- end menu -->






</body>
</html>
```

**The ddmenu.css file:**

```
/* ---------------------------------------------
Keyboard accessible dropdown menu
Author:Adriana Palazova
Version:22 February 2009
last rev.: 19 October 2009
gratitude to Matthew Carroll - http://carroll.org.uk/sandbox/suckerfish/bones2.html
and
Alan Gresley and Duncan Hill - http://css-class.com/articles/ursidae/
------------------------------------------------ */
#ddmenu {font: bold 10pt Arial,Helvetica;border: 2px solid gray;}

/*#ddmenu a:link {text-decoration:none}*/

/*#ddmenu a:visited {text-decoration:none}*/

#ddmenu a:hover, #ddmenu a:focus, #ddmenu a:active {text-decoration:underline}

/* --- TOP LEVEL MENU STYLES --- */
#ddmenu li{list-style-type:none;}

#ddmenu 
{
    float:left; 
    display:inline; 
    width:100%; 
    padding:0; 
    background:#fff0ca; /*#414141;*/
}



#ddmenu li 
{
    position:relative; 
    float:left; 
    /*border-right:1px solid /*#fff; */
    background:#fff0ca;/*#414141; */
    font-weight:bold

}

#ddmenu li a 
{
    display:block; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*width:7em; */
    padding:5px 0.7em 7px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    /*border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;*/
    /*border-width:1px 1px 0; 
    border-style:solid; */
    /*border-color:#3e8ebe #0b3965 #003 #3e8ebe;*/
    /*color:#fff*/
}

/* --- SUB MENU ITEMS --- */

#ddmenu li li 
{
    border:0 none; 
    font-weight:normal; 
    z-index:20
} /* no width here because of IE */

#ddmenu li li a 
{
    /*width:11em; */
    padding:5px 0.5em 7px; 
    border-width:1px
} 

#ddmenu ul > li 
{
    display:block; 
    float:none;
    text-align:left;

} /* for Opera */

/* --- SUB MENU FIRST LEVEL INITIAL POSITION --- */  

#ddmenu ul 
{
    position:absolute; 
    left:-9999px; 
    top:100%; 
    /*width:12em; */
    padding:0; 
    border:1px solid #003

}

/*for modern browsers:*/
#ddmenu li > ul  
{
    top:auto; 
    width:auto
}

/*see the conditional comments for IE7*/

/* --- SHOW FIRST LEVEL SUB MENU --- */
/*For ie6:*/
#ddmenu li.sfhover ul,
#ddmenu li a:active ul,
#ddmenu li.sffocusparent ul,
/* menu points to the right */
/*#ddmenu li a.sffocus ul {left:0}*/
/*#ddmenu li a.sffocus ul {left:-10em} */
/*#scooby li a.sffocus ul {left:-22em} */

/* for modern browsers + IE7:*/
#ddmenu li:hover > ul,
#ddmenu li.sfhover > ul,
#ddmenu li.sffocusparent > ul,
#ddmenu li a:active > ul,
#ddmenu li a:focus + ul,
/* menu points to the right */
/*#ddmenu li a.sffocus + ul {left:auto}*/
#ddmenu li a.sffocus + ul {left:-10em}




/* --- SUB MENU SECOND LEVEL and following levels UNHOVERED POSITION --- */  

#ddmenu li:hover ul ul,
#ddmenu li:active ul ul,
#ddmenu a:focus ul ul,
#ddmenu li.sfhover ul ul,
#ddmenu a.sffocus ul ul,
#ddmenu li.sffocusparent ul ul,
#ddmenu li.sffocus ul ul {left:-9999px}

/* --- SHOW SECOND LEVEL SUB MENU --- */

/* For ie6: */
#ddmenu ul li a:hover ul, #ddmenu ul li.sfhover ul,
#ddmenu ul li a:active ul,
#ddmenu ul li.sffocusparent ul,
/* use a positive number to point the submenu to the right, use 12em for margin-left*/
#ddmenu ul li.sffocus ul {margin-left: -22em; top:-1px; left:1px}

/* for modern browsers + IE7: */
#ddmenu ul li:hover > ul,
#ddmenu ul li.sfhover > ul,
#ddmenu li li a.sffocus + ul,
/* use a positive number to point the submenu to the right, use 12 em for margin-left*/
#ddmenu li li.sffocus > ul {margin-left: -22em; top:-1px; left:1px}




/* --- SUB LEVEL positions for JavaScript  OFF - thanks http://css-class.com/articles/ursidae/ --- */ 

/* --- The focus position for submenu anchors --- */
#ddmenu.jsoff li li a:focus, #ddmenu.jsoff li li a:active { /* --- THE FOCUS POSITION FOR FIRST SUB MENU ANCHORS --- */
    position:relative;
    left:9999px;
    top:-1px;
    z-index:21;
}
#ddmenu.jsoff li li li a:focus, #ddmenu.jsoff li li li a:active { /* --- THE FOCUS POSITION FOR SECOND SUB MENU ANCHORS --- */
    left:19999px;
    margin-left:12em;
    top:-2.9em;
}

/* --- The hovered position for submenu anchors when the anchor is in focus --- */
#ddmenu.jsoff li:hover li a:focus, #ddmenu.jsoff li:hover li a:active { 
    position:relative; left:auto; top:-1px; margin-left:0}

#ddmenu.jsoff li:hover a:focus + ul { /* --- THE POSITION OF FIRST LEVEL SUB MENU, WHEN THE PARENT IS FOCUSSED AND HOVERED --- */
    margin-left:0px;
}
#ddmenu.jsoff li li a:focus + ul { /* --- THE POSITION OF SECOND LEVEL SUB MENU, WHEN THE PARENT IS FOCUSSED FOR JavaScript  OFF --- */
    top:-1px;
    left:12em;
    margin-left:10000px;
}
#ddmenu.jsoff li:hover li a:focus + ul { /* --- THE POSITION OF SECOND LEVEL SUB MENU, WHEN THE PARENT IS FOCUSSED AND HOVERED --- */
    left:12em;
    margin-left:1px;
}

/* --- BACKGROUND IMAGES OF PARENT ITEMS --- */

#ddmenu li a.mum {
  BACKGROUND: url(../images/down.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 50%;
}
#ddmenu ul li a.mum 
{
    BACKGROUND: url(../images/right.gif);
}

/* --- LINK HOVER STYLES --- */

#ddmenu li a:link, #ddmenu li a:visited  {background-color:transparent}
#ddmenu li a:hover, #ddmenu li:hover a, #ddmenu li a:focus, #ddmenu li a:active, 
#ddmenu li.sfhover a, #ddmenu li a.sffocus, #ddmenu li.sffocusparent a {background-color:#fff0ca/*#135*/}/* top level background hover color */

#ddmenu li li a:link, #ddmenu li li a:visited  {background-color:transparent}
#ddmenu ul li a:hover, #ddmenu ul li:hover a, #ddmenu ul li a:focus, #ddmenu ul li a:active, 
#ddmenu ul li.sfhover a, #ddmenu ul li a.sffocus, #ddmenu ul li.sffocusparent a {background-color:blue;color:#fff0ca;}

#ddmenu li li li a:link, #ddmenu li li li a:visited  {background-color:transparent}
#ddmenu li li li a:hover, #ddmenu li li li:hover a, #ddmenu li li li a:focus, #ddmenu li li li a:active, 
#ddmenu li li li.sfhover a, #ddmenu li li li a.sffocus, #ddmenu li li li.sffocusparent a {background-color:blue;color:#fff0ca;} /*{background-color:#135}*/

/* <!--[if IE 7]> */

#ddmenu li > ul  {top:100%}

#ddmenu a
{
    background: url(../images/down.gif) no-repeat -95% -50%;
}

#ddmenu ul li:hover > ul, #ddmenu ul li.sfhover > ul, 
#ddmenu li li a.sffocus + ul, #ddmenu ul li.sffocusparent > ul {left:0}
```

**The ddmenu.js file:**

```
var menuID = 'ddmenu';
/* --- gratitude to Matthew Carroll - http://carroll.org.uk/ - http://carroll.org.uk/sandbox/suckerfish/bones2.html
  based on http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/ --- */
function accessible_menus_ie() {
  var sfEls = document.getElementById(menuID).getElementsByTagName('LI');
  for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
    sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
      this.className+=(this.className.length>0? ' ': '') + 'sfhover';
      this.parentNode.className+=(this.parentNode.className.length>0? ' ': '') + 'sfhover';
    }
    sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
      this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp('( ?|^)sfhover\\b'), '');
      this.parentNode.className=this.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('( ?|^)sfhover\\b'), '');
    }
  }
}
function accessible_menus() {
  var ddMenu = document.getElementById(menuID);
  ddMenu.className = ddMenu.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)jsoff(\\s|$)'), '');
  var mcEls = document.getElementById(menuID).getElementsByTagName('A');
  for (var i=0; i<mcEls.length; i++) {
    mcEls[i].onfocus=function() {
      this.className = this.className ? this.className + ' sffocus' : 'sffocus'; //a:focus
      this.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.className ? this.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //li < a:focus
      this.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.className ? this.parentNode.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //ul < li < a:focus
      if(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI') { //li < ul < li < a:focus
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className ? this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //li < ul < li < a:focus
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className ? this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //ul < li < ul < li < a:focus
        if(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI') {  //li < ul < li < ul < li < a:focus
          this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className ? this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //li < ul < li < ul < li < a:focus
          this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className ?this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className + ' sffocusparent' : 'sffocusparent'; //ul < li < ul < li < ul < li < a:focus
        }
      }
    }
    mcEls[i].onblur = function() {
      this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocus'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
      this.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
      this.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
      if(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI') {
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
        if(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName == 'LI') {
          this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');
          this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+'sffocusparent'+'(\\s|$)'), '');

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// only ie needs the sfHover script. all need the accessibility script...

// thanks Brothercake - Generic onload - GO1.1 - http://www.brothercake.com/site/resources/scripts/onload/
if(typeof window.addEventListener != 'undefined') { //.. gecko, safari, konqueror and standard
    window.addEventListener('load', accessible_menus, false);}
else if(typeof document.addEventListener != 'undefined') { //.. opera
    document.addEventListener('load', accessible_menus, false);}
else if(typeof window.attachEvent != 'undefined') { //.. win/ie
    window.attachEvent('onload', accessible_menus_ie);
    window.attachEvent('onload', accessible_menus);}
//** remove this condition to degrade older browsers
else {  //.. mac/ie5 and anything else that gets this far
  if(typeof window.onload == 'function') { //if there's an existing onload function
    var existing = window.onload; //store it
    window.onload = function() { //add new onload handler
      existing(); //call existing onload function
      //call generic onload function
      accessible_menus_ie();
      accessible_menus();
    };
  } else {
    window.onload = function() { //setup onload function
      accessible_menus_ie();
      accessible_menus();
    };  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the section where it says `/* --- SHOW FIRST LEVEL SUB MENU --- */`, try changing the value of `left` to `0em` instead of `left:-10em;`. I've never played with this plugin before, but that fixed it on my end. There's two instances of it. You want to change the second in the "Modern browsers" section. This would be easier with line numbers.